# Test Page for creating Application for LinkedIn integration

Tags: integration-testing, linkedin-api

Is there any test pages I can specify while creating LinkedIn Application.
As I am doing LinkedIn Integration POC, I need to create application which needs a URL of the company page
I am not able to create a test page from my LinkedIn login.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which type of integration you should test but you could try with these [Test Organizations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/organizations#test-organizations) (company pages):

```
LinkedIn offers two dedicated organizations for testing. You do not have to be an ADMINISTRATOR to make API calls to these organizations.

TEST ORGANIZATIONS

Name        URL                                         Organization URN
DevTestCo   https://www.linkedin.com/company/devtestco  urn:li:organization:2414183
Test University http://www.linkedin.com/school/6177438  urn:li:organization:6177438


 Note

Anyone can view shares posted to a test organization. When you post shares, make sure to exclude information that should not be public.
```